# logback.groovy configuration not working after groovy update

Tags: java, groovy, configuration, logback, slf4j

Working a project update, we updated groovy dependency for our java (gradle) project to version 4.0.4. Now, however, our **logback.groovy** configuration is no longer working.
The issue is that the appender property closures no longer seem to apply to the property that we are configuring (eg. **PatternLayoutEncoder**), but the appender itself.

versions:

- logback-classic: **ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.7**
- groovy: **org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.4**

previous groovy version was `2.5.x`.

Simple logback.groovy file:

```
statusListener(OnConsoleStatusListener)

appender("CONSOLE", ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    }
}

root(DEBUG, ["CONSOLE"])
```

error log:

```
09:02:39,743 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@79f227a9 - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
09:02:39,810 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@79f227a9 - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:02:39,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@79f227a9 - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
09:02:39,913 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.AppenderDelegate@27e32fe4 - Appender [CONSOLE] of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender] has no appplicable [pattern] property 
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Iterator (java.lang.String and java.util.Iterator are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.toList(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3293)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asCollection(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:11550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.minus(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:13702)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.minus(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:13609)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$523.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ComponentDelegate.analyzeArgs(ComponentDelegate.groovy:111)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ComponentDelegate$analyzeArgs.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ComponentDelegate.methodMissing(ComponentDelegate.groovy:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:343)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:926)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1451)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.doInvokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1373)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1103)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:330)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:318)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:4)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:343)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:328)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate.appender(ConfigurationDelegate.groovy:143)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:343)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MixinInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(MixinInstanceMetaMethod.java:61)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:328)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:318)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
    at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:77)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator$run.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:44)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(GafferUtil.java:43)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:67)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
```

This looks like the main error: `Appender [CONSOLE] of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender] has no appplicable [pattern]`, though `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Iterator (java.lang.String and java.util.Iterator are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')` could be something else as well, I guess.

XML configuration seems to work fine (and I know that groovy config is deprecated), but we have a ton of logback.groovy configuration files in various places and would like to use those for the time being, if possible...